# Restrict Regex to accept certain format

Tags: regex

Right now, Regex say is valid a date if I have 200011 - Which is Jan 1st 2000
but i want to restrict that to have the format YYYYMMDD so it will accept only 20000101 as a valid date. How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))([-\/.]?)(?:0?2\1(?:29)))|(?:(?:[1-9]\d{3})([-\/.]?)(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\2(?:31))|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\2(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))$
```

Comment: In what language?  Most offer superior ways for date validation/parsing than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `?` after all `0`s:

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))([-\/.]?)(?:02\1(?:29)))|(?:(?:[1-9]\d{3})([-\/.]?)(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])\2(?:31))|(?:(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])\2(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\2(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lf0QH3/1)

For example, the last `0?[1-9]` would match `0` one or zero times, and then a non-zero digit. When you remove `?` quantifier, the `0` will become required.